# Sending down additional Parameters in jqGrid url option

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid-asp.net

I need to send down an extra parameter or two to my url method in jqGrid.  Is there a way to do that?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#frTable").jqGrid ({
            cmTemplate: { sortable: false },
            caption: '@TempData["POPNAME"]' + ' Population',
            url: '/Encounters/GetAjaxPagedGridData/'+ @TempData["POPULATIONID"]+'',
            ...
```

This would be the method that I am trying to hit...

```
    public string GetAjaxPagedGridData(int page, int rows, int popId) {
        return "";
    }
```

I was thinking something like this

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetAjaxPagedGridData", "Encounters", new { popId = TempData["POPULATIONID"] })'
```

Answer (score 0):

use post data option for example do the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#frTable").jqGrid ({
        cmTemplate: { sortable: false },
        caption: '@TempData["POPNAME"]' + ' Population',
        url: '/Encounters/GetAjaxPagedGridData/',
        postdata: {popId : TempData["POPULATIONID"],
                   // and any other parameters that you need to pass}
```

Comment: can I still use the mtype of 'GET'